# How to display latest appcfg upload date/time in GAE-app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to make it easy to display the date of when my GAE web application was last updated.

Anyone who knows how to retreive information from the GAE-account about the latest appcfg upload and make that date/time display on a jsp-page?
(I use Java)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse this information from [`SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty#applicationVersion): Docs say:

```
The major version number for the currently running version of the application 
plus a timestamp at which it was deployed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't available from inside an app.

Comment: How about SystemProperty.applicationVersion? The docs say it contains a timestamp at which it was deployed.

Comment: @PeterKnego News to me. There's definitely nothing in the Python environment that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in python-land, but you might be able to do the same in Java.  I have an entity in the datstore that just keeps the last updated time.

I have my own deploy script (actually, to be precise, I'm using django-nonrel, which has a wrapper around appcfg.py, the GAE deploy script for python, which I've extended) which uses the remote-api to update that entity if a deploy succeeds.